# AWS SNS event skipped for second update of S3 Object within 2 seconds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have two Lambda's that responds to SNS Notifications on a non-fifo topic from a ObjectCreated:* event on an S3 object. Within a margin of 2 seconds, the S3 object is updated twice. My subscribed lambda's seem to only respond to the first update. Is this known behaviour? Only one event seems to have been emitted.

If the updates where published as two records in one SNS Event, my application would be prepared to handle both events. Unfortunately, a second record does not seem to be available in the payload.

Comment: Does your AWS Lambda function loop through the event `Records`, such that it can process multiple messages with the one invocation? I'd be interested to see the `for` loop that processes those records.

Comment: @John Rotenstein I've asked that question below and it seems he has the logic implemented to handle multiple records in single event.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has [an archived developer’s guide](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/NotificationHowTo.md) which states:

> Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least
> once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in seconds but can
> sometimes take a minute or longer. **If two writes are made to a single
> non-versioned object at the same time, it is possible that only a
> single event notification will be sent.** If you want to ensure that an
> event notification is sent for every successful write, you can enable
> versioning on your bucket. With versioning, every successful write
> will create a new version of your object and will also send an event
> notification.

However, in [the new open source user’s guide] (April, 2021), this note has been removed.

I think turning on versioning will probably fix this error, but this also comes with the extra costs.

I’m awaiting the answer on a support ticket, I promise to update this answer with my latest findings. In the meanwhile, this should offer a workaround along with some guidance on the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of AWS systems have an eventual consistency model. In the case of S3 updating objects have eventual consistency across 3 Availability Zones.

In short, you are updating an object to one of the S3 instances before the event trigger on that instance of S3.

Can it be that you have both events in the same payload?

Comment: If the updates where published as two records in one SNS Event, my application would be prepared to handle both events. Unfortunately, a second record does not seem to be available in the payload.

Comment: might it be that due to the Availability Zones, the events are actually merged into 1 event with the same eventTime?

Comment: That might be. Are you able to replicate this or does it not happen sporadically?

Comment: I'm afraid this only happens very rarely. I will try to replicate it in a more debuggable environment and get back to you.

Comment: So with updating I know S3 actually does a put. Did you try enabling versioning?

Comment: Versioning is currently disabled. I'm currently trying to replicate the issue and if found, enable bucket versioning and see if that fixes the issue.